# 2D texture paint quality to 3D

Tags: 3d-view, interface, image, texture-painting, 2d

Because of Masking[*](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/zKgbbc/), I try to move from Image Editor to Texture Paint in 3D Viewport . With  *Viewport Shading \ Material Preview \ Diffuse Color*  and  *Material Properties \ Texture Interpolation \ Closest*, I almost can replace it . But I met these issues:

1. Every time when I Eyedrop some colors from 3D Viewport, picked color is brighter than the color i was picking . (3D Viewport still has modified rendering brightness, and I don't know what to do that would fix this)
2. Soften works with threshold of 9%, compared to fine 5% in Image Editor . ;

[Video](https://pixeldrain.com/u/ziJQF3Ez)

Does anyone know how to solve these ?

Comment: If you want the same color as in viewport with the color pipette, change the color management device to None

Comment: @Gorgious ` Render Properties \ Color Management ` didn't help, but ` Viewport Shading \ Solid \ Flat ` solved the Eyedropper issue .

Comment: The solution stopped working after creating other project .